# Inconveniente de Lectura de archivo de Excel en R Studio

Tags: r, rstudio

Cordial saludo equipo espero se encuentren bien, quiero pedirles el favor con lo siguiente :

Dentro de R Studio estoy realizando la lectura de un archivo en Excel, en un script, por medio de la siguiente instrucción:

```
CEP_excel <- read_excel("CEP_sep-oct_2017.xlsx")
```

y el compilador de R Studio me muestra el siguiente error:

```
Error: `path` does not exist: ‘CEP_sep-oct_2017.xlsx
```

Vale mencioar que el archivo en excel (.xlsx), lo tengo en la misma ubicacion en donde tengo almacenado el Script en R Studio

y que previamente corrí el siguiente comando:  `library(readxl)` en donde me muestra la siguiente advertencia:

```
Warning message:
package ‘readxl’ was built under R version 4.1.3
```

Verificando la version del R Studio que tengo, es la 1.4.1717

Agradezco por favor me indiquen por que razón no me funciona la lectura del archvo en Excel:

```
CEP_excel <- read_excel("CEP_sep-oct_2017.xlsx")
```

Saludos!

Comment: Ejecuta `getwd()`, ese es el directorio en el que estás trabajando (independientemente de donde tengas guardado el script), de no ser la carpeta en la que está el documento Excel, ejecuta `setwd()` introduciendo en medio la dirección deseada

Comment: No hay mucho que podamos decirte, si no existe es que no existe, tal vez estas asumiendo que la carpeta de trabajo es una y en realidad es otra

Comment: Hola R18, lo que hice, fue lo sigjuiente:                                                                   puse esto:       setwd("C:/Users/hecamava/Documents/R")                                                          Luego puse    CEP_excel <- read_excel("CEP_sep-oct_2017.xlsx")                            
 Y ahora me muestra esto                                                                                   
 Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  namespace ‘rlang’ 0.4.11 is being loaded, but >= 1.0.2 is required
>

Comment: No se por que dicen que necesito mas espacio

Comment: Usar `setwd()` no es un buena práctica, pero al menos pareciera que has solucionado el error inicial, pero hora tienes otro problema y es que deberías actualizar `rlang`

Answer (score 0):

ese error vine de la instalación, te recomiendo reinstalarlo y elegir tú el directorio, tuve el mismo problema al tener el onedrive activado, reinstalar y escribe el directorio donde lo guardes manualmente.Tambien puedes usar r studio cloud te dejo el link https://posit.cloud/

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).